# Запись с вариантами integer и double

Tags: delphi, запись

Для совместимости расчётных модулей и обмена данными между различными поколениями приборов (старые используют целочисленный тип позиции, новые, более точные, - с плавающей точкой) пришлось ввести такой тип:

```
type
  TDataRec = record
    <...>
    case integer of
      0: pos: integer;
      1: position:double;
  end;
  TDataAr = array of TDataRec;
```

В целом, всё работает, неудобств, кроме увеличения места хранения и небольшого лага по времени, не отмечаем.
Смущает следующее: double - 64 бита, integer - 32. Какие ловушки могут быть из-за этого? Стоит ли ввести дополнительное поле в 32 бита как заглушку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ловушек нет. Под эти поля отводится место по размеру наибольшего типа.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Variant_Parts_in_Records

> For each record instance, the compiler allocates enough memory to hold
>   all the fields in the largest variant.

---

Так как речь об обмене данными между приборами, я бы использовал `packed record`. Возможно, Вы это делаете директивно: `{$A1}` или `{$A-}`.